# Generate all unique Permutations with every number occurring twice in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, combinatorics

I am looking for an efficient Algorithm in Java to find all unique permutations of the numbers 1 through N where every number occurs twice.

so for example:
N = 2 -> 1122, 1221, 2211, 1212, 2121, 2112

what I have so far is [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) algorithm.
From there I filter out all the multiple occurrences of a permutation.
This however is very inefficient and gets exponentially worse because it returns (N*2)! permutations before filtering.

is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Comment: As far as I know, if a question is about how to improve code that works, the question should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: For views on including links to code, as opposed to including the code in the question, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer But this isn't about the existing code.

Comment: @Sören, after reviewing the link I believe you are correct that I misunderstood the question.

Comment: In the future, please don't post links to code.  Best is to paste the code in your question.  If it isn't yours, provide a citation.

Comment: https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm